# Consul with ngix

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, web, consul

I am trying to setup consul with nginx, tried consul with spring dependency that worked for me, but I am using nginx for reverse proxy and load balancing that's why I have to configure consul with nginx, I am not using docker as of now, I have seen many tutorials for docker, nginx and consul.

but I just only want the configuration for nginx and consul, I am not getting how to start and where to start

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use fabio ?

[FabioLB](https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio) is the Consul's load balancer which also make reverse proxy.

And it connects to consul in a instant.

How it works??
In your docker container you have to put a environment variable with the url-prefix-site.example.com and that's it.

Hope it helps